# Ajax post doesn't populate data to a dropdown select list

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

What I missing about posting to ActionMethods to pull data here ?

I need to do a simple javascript/jquery call to an ActionMethod that will populatel my drop down menu with data from my Json object of type IQueryable ( or List ).

So I tried two options:

```
    function populateuUsers(id) {
    $.post("/User/GetUsersJson/", { id: id }, function (data) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
            alert("Empty");

        }

        $.each(data, function (item) {
            alert(item);
            $("#user-list").append(
                $("<option></option>").text(data[item].FullName).val(data[item].Id)
                );
        });

    }, "json");
}
```

I get an error that "data is undefined"

Then I tried:

```
    function populateUsers(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        url: "/User/GetUsersJson/" + id,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $.each(data, function (item) {
                alert(item);
                $("#users-list").append(
                    $("<option></option>").text(data[item].FullName).val(data[item].Id));

            });
        },
        error:function()
            {
                alert(data);
            }

    });
}
```

Doesn't work either.
Something to note...I set break points and did verify that data in GetUsersJson Action method User controller gets properly populated and returned to the javascript function.

Why is it not working then ? Why is "data undefined" and it acts like there nothing returned ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your GetUsersJson action look like on the controller?

Comment: Just pulling data from repository and doing return Json(myUsers). myUsers object is of type IQueryable<User>.

I see about 10 users in that list object when debug with a break point. Let me know if you would like to see the actual code.

Comment: Maybe it acts as if nothing is returned because nothing is returned. Have you opened your browser debugger and set a breakpoint on the callback function and actually inspected the data object to see what, if anything, is in it?

Comment: Yeah, there is data it and breakpoint showed it. Besides, if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
            alert("Empty"); would trigger otherwise

Comment: what does your alert(data) popup?

Comment: "data is undefined"
...As I'm digging through this problem I think it has something to do with the error I'm picking up in Fiddler related to my Json object:
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'User' 
Hmmm...Going to dig some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the anonymous function that you're passing to `$.each`, `data` is not defined. Instead you should pass two variables to that function. Something like:

```
$.each(data, function (key, item) {
    alert(item);
    $("#users-list").append(
        $("<option></option>").text(item.FullName).val(item.Id));

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused. What's a "key" in this case ?

Comment: Key is what you were calling `item` before. It's the key of the map that you're iterating through. It might help if you posted the JSON structure.